# Access custom fields in auth in firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to access custom fields in my auth for controlling access to my data in firebase, The users field in firebase looks like this

```
users: {
    email: string,
    isAdmin: boolean,
    name: string
}
```

I have this rules for ensuring that only admin can read the entire table of orders

```
"orders":{
    "$userOrders": {
        ".read": "$userOrders == auth.uid || auth.isAdmin == true",
        "$eachUserOrder": {
            ".read": "$userOrders == auth.uid || auth.isAdmin == true",
            ".write": "!data.exists()"
         }
    },
    ".read": "auth.isAdmin === true"
},
```

In the simulation if I pass this as part of the token it works,

```
{
    "provider": "anonymous",
    "uid": "559a9195-e2ab-4039-91ac-877d2afca482",
    "isAdmin": true
}
```

But for users with the field isAdmin set to true on the browser it says permission denied.

> util.js:233 FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. Error: permission_denied at /orders: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.

I don't understand what is wrong at this time.

Comment: The rules you shared give no-one write permission to `/orders`. The error message says that you're trying to write to `/orders`. Without seeing the code that raises the warning, it'll be hard to say more than that.

Comment: Is the `isAdmin` flag stored in the database? How do you set that for the user? If so, you need to do something like `root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('isAdmin').val() == true`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  No I am making a read operation

Comment: @MichaelBleigh this seems to work for me. Thanks.